# Using Material Design Toolkit, Flyouts in Mahapps Metro Window don't work correctly

Tags: wpf, material-design, mahapps.metro, flyout

**Context**: I'm using Mahapps.Metro Flyouts with Material Design toolkits.

**Problem**: When a `Flyout` opens it is not positioned as specified. For example, if I set the `Flyout` to be at the `Bottom` of the `Window` it gets positioned at the vertical center.

I’ve set up the App.xaml to support both Mahapps and Material Design. I also do a mapping of the themes and accents for a consistent experience.

I took the configuration as shown in the MD WIKI. I got a Metro Window and my application uses various controls with Mahapps and Material Design styling – without any trouble. Only the flyouts don’t work correctly.

To isolate the problem I reduced my application to a minimum. Furthermore I took the example flyout from the Material Design Mahapps demo application.
**While the demo application runs perfectly, it doesn’t work in the context of my application.**

If I leave the Mahapps-MD compatibility stuff out of my App.xaml the flyout works correctly, but of course without the MD theming.

#### App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="Frontend.App" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Frontend" 
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             d1p1:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:UiLogic="clr-namespace:EPM.Frontend.Logic;assembly=Frontend.Logic">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <UiLogic:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
                </ResourceDictionary>

                <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />

                <!-- Material Design -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />

                <!-- Material Design: MahApps Compatibility -->
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.MahApps.Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.MahApps.Defaults.xaml" />
                <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.MahApps.Flyout.xaml" />-->

                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Colors.xaml"/>

            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <!-- MahApps Brushes -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HighlightBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush2" Color="{DynamicResource Primary400}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush3" Color="{DynamicResource Primary300}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush4" Color="{DynamicResource Primary200}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowTitleColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentSelectedColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ProgressBrush" EndPoint="0.001,0.5" StartPoint="1.002,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Primary700}" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Primary300}" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CheckmarkFill" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RightArrowFill" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundColorBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500Foreground}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IdealForegroundDisabledBrush" Color="{DynamicResource Primary500}" Opacity="0.4"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

#### Window (reduced to the relevant stuff):

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Frontend.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EPM.Frontend"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        xmlns:iconPacks="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/iconpacks"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
        Title="electronic platform manager" Width="732" Height="452"
        Background="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignPaper}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"
        EnableDWMDropShadow="True">

   <Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>
        <Controls:FlyoutsControl x:Name="flyoutsControl">
            <Controls:Flyout x:Name="LeftFlyout" Position="Bottom" Header="Settings" materialDesign:FlyoutAssist.HeaderColorMode="Accent" IsOpen="True" Height="80">
                <local:FlyoutContent />
            </Controls:Flyout>
        </Controls:FlyoutsControl>
    </Controls:MetroWindow.Flyouts>

</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

#### Packages I'm using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="CommonServiceLocator" version="1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MahApps.Metro" version="1.4.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MahApps.Metro.IconPacks" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MahApps.Metro.Resources" version="0.6.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MaterialDesignColors" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MaterialDesignThemes" version="2.2.1.750" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps" version="0.0.8" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MvvmLight" version="5.3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MvvmLightLibs" version="5.3.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

#### Output:

[image]

After trying a few hours getting this to work I’ve still no clue what the problem could be. Any hint is highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Marcus

Comment: The current version of MaterialDesignThemes doesn't work with MahApps v1.4.1. I will push an update to the repo.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I'll try it out as soon as the new version is available.

Comment: Hi guys, I've merged @punker76 's changes, and pushed to nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialDesignThemes.MahApps/0.0.9

Comment: Hi, I pulled 0.0.9 into my project. At startup I've got a XamlParseException, The inner exception says that there is a problem with loading the assembly MahApps.Metro, because of a mismatch between manifest definition and assembly reference. I changed back to 0.0.8 an the exception disappeared. ({"Die Datei oder Assembly \"MahApps.Metro, PublicKeyToken=null\" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein.